# phonegap inapp browser certificate hyperlink not opening

Tags: cordova, ssl, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to open a link through phonegap's inapp browser. The link has SSL certificate along with it and its not opening up in mobile devices.
Can someone please tell me if I have to update my config file or something else that I have to do in order to get this done ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to be sure that the link (or domain) you are trying to open is **whitelisted**.
To whitelist URLs you have to add the following entry to your `config.xml`

```
<access origin="www.domain-to-access.com" />
```

Comment: I think problem is with the ssl certificate of the particular link I am using, other https requests are working fine.

Comment: I had same issue(form is not submitting) like this when accessing to https payment gateway on inapp browser. Using this method works for me. Thanks.